# how automatically zoom webpage depend on resolution

Tags: javascript, zooming, html, resolution

I'm working on website and have to convert from psd(photoshop) file to html and there was one issue that webpage was very big like 3300px x 2800px and I zoom out it 40.881 % to fix website size. And now size is good on 1366x768 resolution, but for example on 1280 x 700 or bigger resolution website is always scrollable horizontally or there are white space in right side.

How can I depend on screen resolution zoom in or zoom out my background?

[image: Example zoom for 1366x768 resolution]

Answer (score 0):

set the image with and height to 100% on css?

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the vw and vh units for your measurements. Example:

```
h1 { font-size: 0.5vw }
```

Would make the font size if a h1 tag half the viewport width of the element that it's contained in.

The vw adjusts according to width and vh to height.